# Azure functions: return JSON object

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

Consider:

```python
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = {"test":"jjj"}
    return func.HttpResponse(name)
```

Above is my Azure function (V2) using Python preview.

If I return

```python
func.HttpResponse(f"{name}")
```

it works, but if I return a dict object it does not.

The error displayed is:

> Exception: TypeError: reponse is expected to be either of str, bytes, or bytearray, got dict

Comment: Have you tried serializing your dict object to JSON before returning it?

Comment: @maswadkar Take a look. Though its not exact solution for your problem but help you to get into this what you need to do or your work around. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: Did it literally output "reponse" (not "[response](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/response#Noun)")?

Answer (score 52):

You need to convert your dictionary to a JSON string using the built-in JSON library - *[json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)*.

Then you can set the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME_header_fields) (Content-Type) of your function to `application/json`. By default [Azure functions HttpResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httpresponse?view=azure-python) returns `text/plain` Content-Type.

```py
import json
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = {"test":"jjj"}
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(name),
        mimetype="application/json",
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! To get more compact JSON, you should do `json.dumps(name, separators=(',', ':')`

Comment: @maswadkar Could you accept this as the answer if it answered your question? It looks like this has been helpful to the community.

Answer (score 8):

Better way:

```
func.HttpResponse.mimetype = 'application/json'
func.HttpResponse.charset = 'utf-8'

return func.HttpResponse(json_object)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why this is better? It looks like this is modifying global variables in a foreign module, which is an ugly side effect. Also, I'm simply getting a (runtime) `TypeError` if I don't serialize the `json_object` myself. And type checking the code with mypy/pyright fails, because the first argument to `HttpResponse` is typed as `str | bytes`, so you cannot just pass in your raw data, right? Also, specifying the charset as `utf-8` is redundant, because it is the default anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am not a Python expert. I am just trying to let you know what the issue is all about.

So on Azure function if you look, it would seem its return type is `IActionResult`. If you `decompile` it, you would see:

```cs
IActionResult IConvertToActionResult.Convert()
    {
      ActionResult result = this.Result;
      if (result != null)
        return (IActionResult) result;
      return (IActionResult) new ObjectResult((object) this.Value)
      {
        DeclaredType = typeof (TValue)
      };
    }
```

So it expects an object from you rather than a Dictionary or List or any kind of generics type. But if you convert it into an object like `OkObjectResult`, you wouldn't encounter any compile error. See the example below:

```cs
IDictionary<int, string> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
MyDictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "One"));
MyDictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Two"));

// As we have to return IAction Type, so converting to IAction class
// using OkObjectResult we can even use OkResult
return new MyDictionary;
```

The above code would encounter your compile error. Because it does not support Dictionary or List Or any generic directly. See the screenshot below:

[image]

See what the error said:

[image]

But if you convert your Dictionary or List Or any generic into an object type, it will resolve your issue for sure. See the below example:

```cs
IDictionary<int, string> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
MyDictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "One"));
MyDictionary.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Two"));

// So have converted MyDictionary into Object type that the compiler deserve. And no compile error encountered.
return new OkObjectResult(MyDictionary);
```

See the screenshot below:

[image]

**Note:** If you try to parse your `func.HttpResponse(name)` into an object then finally return, your problem should resolve. So you can try to add a reference to this package in your project (`import json`) and try the below code:

```
import json

name = {"test":"jjj"}

print(json.dumps(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is:

```py
return func.HttpResponse(
   body = name,
   status_code = 200
)
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httpresponse?view=azure-python) for more information on the HttpResponse class.

Comment: This is not the solution and raises the same exception as the original post. `Exception: TypeError: reponse is expected to be either of str, bytes, or bytearray, got dict`

Comment: right, the api might have changed, I should have mentioned which version this was for.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
 import json

     return func.HttpResponse (
        json.dumps({
        'lat': lat,
        'lon': lon

        })
     )
```

Comment: That is not valid Python by itself (indentation). Is it only a snippet? Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68552786/edit) in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

what about this, create a json object (json dumps creates a json from a dictonary) and return that in the body of your response:

```
# json object
result = {
    "arg1" : variable1,
    "arg2" : variable2
}
result = json.dumps(result, indent = 4) 

return func.HttpResponse(
        body = result,
        status_code=200
)
```